# If a fluid has the complex potential $w(z)=\frac{-\Gamma i}{2 \pi}\operatorname{log}z$ what are its radial and transverse velocity components?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

If a fluid has the complex potential
$$w(z)=\frac{-\Gamma i}{2 \pi}\operatorname{log}z$$
Can anyone show me how to find its radial and transverse velocity components in polar coordinates?

They are meant to be $u_r=0$ and $u_\theta=\frac{\Gamma}{2r \pi}$

Comment: Are you completely sure $u_r = 0$ ?

Comment: @Yrogirg: Yes, this is the complex potential for a vortex, probably should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I've forgot, what is the complex potenial. So,

$$w = \varphi + i \psi$$

where $\varphi$ is a potential and $\psi$ is a stream function.

Thus, $\boldsymbol v = \text{grad} \varphi \;$:

$$v_r = \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial r} = \text{Re} \left[ \frac{\partial \, w(r e^{i \varphi})}{\partial r} \right] $$

$$v_{\theta} = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \theta} = \text{Re} \left[ \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \, w(r e^{i \varphi})}{\partial \theta} \right] $$

You could use stream function $\psi$ instead of potential though.

I've used [FriCAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FriCAS) to evaluate things to the answer:

```
(15) -> D(real(-G*%i/(2*%pi)*log(r*exp(%i*phi))),r)

   (15)  0

(16) -> D(1/r * real(-G*%i/(2*%pi)*log(r*exp(%i*phi))),phi)

            G
   (16)  ──────
         2%pi r
```

Comment: btw, one could swap Re and $\partial$, that is first differentiate, then take the real part.

Comment: Thank you, but could you explain in a little more detail how you found those expressions for $v_r,v_{\theta}$ and how they are implied from $v=\nabla \phi$ as I am unsure, thanks so much!

Comment: Quick explanation --- That's just an expression for gradient in polar coordinates. Personally, I usually consult tables to look up for $\nabla$ or $\Delta$ in various coordinates. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates the part about cylindrical coordinates. Polar coordinates are just cylindrical without $z$. Check also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47618/definition-of-the-gradient-for-non-cartesian-coordinates

Comment: Actually, If you thought $\text{grad} \varphi \;\;$ to be $\left( \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \theta} \right) \;\;\;$ then it doesn't make sence due to inconsistent units. $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \;\;$ divides by meters, while $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \;\;$ is dimensionless.

Comment: I was using $\nabla \phi = (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x},\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y})$
But I see now.. I proved these last year.. I guess i'll just have to remember them!
Thank you so much for your help!