# Vector differential rigourous definition

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, differential

I don't understand how vector differential $d\vec{r}$ is defined rigorously. For a differential $dx$, it can be defined rigorously through differential geometry, where $dx$ is interpreted as a covector. However this view doesn't seem to work for $d\vec{r}$. For example, in Cartesian coordinates $d\vec{r} = dx\space \vec{e_x} + dy\space \vec{e_y}$. I can understand $dx + dy$ as a one form, but I don't know how to interpret $dx\space \vec{e_x} + dy\space \vec{e_y}$.

I'm coming from [curvilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates) wikipedia article, where $d\vec{r}$ is used extensively to get result that helps prove vector operators in non-Cartesian coordinate system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I now understand it a bit more. To answer this question, I don't $d\mathbf{r}$ is a differential form.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you know some differential geometry, so I would recommend you read Loomis and Sternberg's book [Advanced Calculus](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf). In appendix II of chapter $11$, they introduce the notion of a vector valued differential form. The definition is as follows:

> Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold, and $E$ a Banach space over $\Bbb{R}$. An $E$-valued exterior differential form on $M$, of degree $p$, is a function $\omega$ which assigns to each $x \in M$, a function
>   \begin{align}
> \omega(x): \underbrace{(T_xM) \times \dots \times (T_xM)}_{p \text{ times}} \to E,
> \end{align}
>    whereby $\omega(x)$ is (continuous) multilinear and alternating.

Typically when we discuss differential forms, we take $E= \Bbb{R}$. Hence, we get the notion of a 1-form like $dx,dy,dz$. If instead we only assume that $E$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space, then by choosing a basis $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ for $E$, we can uniquely write every $E$-valued exterior differential form $\omega$ as
\begin{equation}
\omega = \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_ie_i
\end{equation}
where $\omega_i$ are $\Bbb{R}$-valued exterior differential forms (i.e the usual kind which you might be used to).
In such a case, we might write the form $\omega$ in vector notation as $(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n)$ (again, refer to the book for a slightly more detailed explanation).

---

A concrete example can be when $E = \Bbb{R}^2$, and we choose the standard basis $e_1,e_2$. Then, once we have the real-valued 1-forms $dx$ and $dy$, we can define the vector-differential form $d\boldsymbol{r}$ as
\begin{equation}
d\boldsymbol{r} := dx \cdot e_1 + dy \cdot e_2 = (dx,dy)
\end{equation}
where the symbols have the meaning as explained above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain how the result in curvilinear coordinates wiki article can be derived? In that article the difference is the basis is not global. E.g. In polar coordinate system, the basis at each point is different. But nevertheless the result still looks like it is using $d\vec{r}$ as a differential form.

Here is the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates#Differential_elements

Comment: Thank you anyway!

Comment: Hi @peek-a-boo. Regarding the wikipedia page on curvilinear coordinates, I think I now get a rather satisfactory understanding. If you're interested, I have posted my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3278237/459936